# Why some programs run slower/laggier with the dedicated graphics card (nvidia optimus) than with the iGPU

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

My question is simple: On Windows 10, some programs like Spotify or Microsoft Office apps seem to be working worse when I force them on the nvidia graphics card, rather than with the intregrated gpu. But I don't understand why, because the dGPU should much more faster than the iGPU.

Comment: -1 This can be easily googled and instantly find an answer.

Comment: (1 I dont know the answer to it and its not intuitive)

Comment: @pigeonburger - You should consider submitting an answer if you know the answer to the author’s question

Comment: With optimus you are using the iGPU to certain extent anyway, if the overhead of offloading the computation to the dGPU is relatively large, i.e. when the performance gain is negligible (which would be the case if the task isn't demanding), then what you experienced could happen, I imagine.

Comment: What models are your computer and graphical adapters?

Comment: @pigeonburger having the answer on Google doesn't really help anyone here though. If we had an answer *here* then fine, you could vote to close it as a duplicate, but we still want to be a knowledgebase of "Hey, I have this problem with my computer. Why does it do that?" and this can well be one of those weird "I didn't realise it worked like that" questions. It might be easy to Google, but only if you know the right terms to put in to begin with.

Comment: @harrymc My computer is an AERO 15 OLED XC (rtx 3070, )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because doing work on the dGPU means that you then have to copy the work done back to the iGPU for display.

Your actual display is connected to your iGPU. That is where your output frame buffers are stored. Your dGPU might have its own dedicated memory, but that is working memory for the GPU itself. Your dGPU lacks display output capabilities because it is intended to be output to a buffer and then copied to the iGPU for display.

For every frame or window rendered on the dGPU you must then copy that window over to the host memory for display.

If you have a fullscreen 1920x1080 image updating at 60Hz then you are copying (1920 x 1080 x 32 x 60)/8 bytes of data per second. 497,664,000. 486 megabytes of data per second just to show a window. Now imagine you just did that with 10, 20 or 30 Windows, forcing everything to render on the dGPU.

The bandwidth of a PCIe gen 3 link is high but not infinite. A laptop might only have an x4 PCIe link due to space and handle anywhere between 1 to 4GB/s depending on generation. You will quickly starve your system of bandwidth with multiple windows.

If you have just one thing running on the dGPU then that overhead may well be acceptable, but once you force every application onto the dGPU then it quickly becomes a bottleneck. There are also going to be a tiny amount of delays added for each frame to be rendered on the dGPU, copied, and then displayed. It should be fast, but with many programs using the bandwidth delays can happen.

Your dGPU may technically be faster at a lot of jobs, but for just general "showing a window" work the iGPU will be more than capable and, because it is the device actually connected to the display, will not have the downsides associated with the dGPU.  It can do far more intelligent desktop composition and rendering than fully rendering each window, copying it over and then (after the work has been done and the bandwidth already wasted) discarding what it doesn't need.

The iGPU is, in modern systems, still pretty powerful. Okay you're not going to play 4k games at 120fps or even 30fps, but for general desktop, Internet, video playing and similar duties they can handle it with plenty of headroom to spare.

Use your dGPU when you actually *need* extra processing power in an application such as a game or something with heavy lifting, graphics wise. Otherwise you are massively penalising performance for no real benefit.

Comment: Thank you so much!!