# Disabling Nvidia GPU for routine tasks

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpu

I have a Windows 10 PC with a NVIDIA GPU. I want to do train some deep learning models on it but the GPU usage of applications like Desktop Window Manager, Client Server Runtime Process and Windows Driver Foundation is between 6-7% with GPU memory usage being 1K MB. Is there a way to disable using the NVIDIA GPU for everything except my deep learning scripts?

Comment: You can disable it in Device Manager. Manual or look for a power shell script.

Comment: I’d say not having a display connected to it could do the trick. Disabling the driver will prevent CUDA etc. from working.

Comment: Only do this if you a) don't have any displays connected to the nvidia GPU or b) can accept the performance ramifications of rendering applications on the alternate GPU and copying the results over PCIe to the "main" GPU as in the one connected to the displays. You are probably talking about the opposite to https://superuser.com/questions/1652452/why-some-programs-run-slower-laggier-with-the-dedicated-graphics-card-nvidia-op/1652487#1652487 but the result is the same in the opposite direction.

Comment: The only applications worth "running" on the alternate display are those that you want displayed on a screen connected to that display, otherwise you should just make use of the GPU that has the displays connected. The performance impact of applications on your dGPU is likely to be minimal, it is what it was designed to do.

Comment: Maybe OP should clarify this is not about a laptop…?

Comment: @DanielB my comments were based on experience having a "full" dGPU in a desktop which effectively reverses the situation compared to a laptop. Windows *prefers* running programs on the dGPU and the situation is reversed, and programs will continue to run on the dGPU even when connected to the iGPU outputs unless you explicitly set it up in the Windows graphics settings. OP is essentially asking to do a "reverse laptop" situation, which sadly still requires the same setup and has the same downsides.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the default Graphics card using the NVIDIA Control panel.

1. right-click on the desktop
2. click on the NVIDIA Control panel
3. under 3D Settings open Manage 3D Settings
4. Change the Preferred graphics processor to your intel onboard GPU

you can also do this for each one of your applications separately

Comment: The "Preferred graphics processor" option doesn't appear for me

Comment: This answer only applies to laptops with switchable graphics (NVIDIA Optimus).

Comment: This worked for me but wondering if it's going to mess with my CUDA and CuDNN at all.